# Explanation how "updated_at" works

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

Can someone explain to a newbie how "updated_at" in a database in Rails works?

I want to implement a "last_updated_by" function and I have no idea how db saves last updated_at date and overwrite a previous one.

I tried to save a user name as a parameter with hidden_field_tag when updating information for my model, but it brings me to nowhere.

Comment: Options might include setting such an attribute manually in the controller or using a `before_save` lifecycle hook. Please be more specific about your setup, what you want to achieve and what you tried so far. I like to help develop a solution to a given problem. However, if you just want to understand how Rails works, then don't ask on stackoverflow. Ask on a different site. Or read up in online tutorials and screencasts and books and blogs.

Comment: Please see my updated question. Your help would be very appreciated!

Comment: Did you include a `last_updated_by` attribute with your model when running the generators? (Or add a database column with a migration?) Please post relevant sections of your view code, your controller code and your `schema.rb`.

Comment: (PS/ by 'post' I mean 'amend your question with')

Comment: `updated_at` is set by Rails automatically when you call save on an object. You want to track the last user to update an object. Your model has no knowledge of who is currently using the application or executing an action. This is something that should happen in your controller. But the bottom line is you want to have a reference column to the users table, and you want to assign that reference to be that of the current user using the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I created the column last_edited_by in my table.
Then I used the update_column method in my controller action for overwriting the last_edited_by value with current user name.

Answer (score 1):

To really see how this works you can check out the source at https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb

It basically checks `has_changes_to_save?` and if it is true sets `updated_at`/`created_at` to `Time.now.utc`.

Answer (score -1):

Im not sure if you want to save the username or just the reference to the user object.

I suggest you to use the [userstamp](https://github.com/delynn/userstamp) gem, it creates the `created_by` and `updated_by` attributes for your models out of the box, you can easily integrate it with your user model.

In case you are using Rails 4 I suggest you to take a look to this thread: [How to configure userstamp for rails 4](https://github.com/delynn/userstamp/issues/22)

UserStamp is not fully supported for rails 4 so that's why you need to take look to the above thread.

Comment: I'd advise all beginners to try and fully understand a problem before using a gem as a shorthand. Using gems is not the easiest way to go all the time. Reading code of gems is a good idea in any case, though :)

Comment: How do you know which user invoked the update within a `before_save` callback?

Comment: Yes you are right I removed that from the answer, I'll go for the gem if I were him.